# Multiprocessing - how to Maximize CPU usage?

Tags: python-multiprocessing, distributed-computing, producer-consumer, hpc

I have a question about patterns/good practices to exploit the full power of CPU.

I have a Queue with several elements and K Processes (K == cpu_counts).
Each Process takes an element from the queue and processes it.

```python
    def worker(self,):
        while True:
            item = self.queue.get(True)
            if item == "STOP":
                break
            self.process_item(item)

    def run(self):
        processes = [Process(target=self.worker) for _ in range(self.n_cpus)]
        for p in processes:
            p.start()
        {.. other code to add elements to self.queue }
```

The **self.process_item(item)** calls an executable and writes the results on an independent file: each computation is independent of the others Processes [In this case, I cannot use multi-threading since I need to change the folder every time in order to run the executable]

The executable runs in about 1 second and it's not particularly CPU expensive.
So, in general, when I run my code, the CPU seems more or less unused since each Process runs the executable on a different core, but the executable per se is not so computationally intensive.

Is there a way to stress the CPU at **full power** and process much more elements faster?

Could increasing K > n_cpus increase the performance or only add **overhead** in switching among processes?

Comment: It depends on what your processes do. For example, if they do a lot of IO (disk reads, network requests, etc.) you can make more executables otherwise there is no point to spawn additional ones.

Comment: Btw, if you are running executables, you really should just use threads in your python application. They are waiting most of the time anyway.

Comment: @AngelicosPhosphoros Yes, a large part of the process work is about copying files from a folder to another, creating new .txt files, and removing other intermediate ones. The problem with threads is that in self.process_item() I have to change the directory to a sub-directory, but in some way, I think I can overcome this issue. Do you think that with thread could be an improvement in performance?

Comment: In that case it probably would stuck in IO. If you copy files on SSD, it probably would be faster if you use threads but on HDD it would be probably better to just copy files sequentically. I said about threads because you run executable from your fork so you run 2 processes per core (one your fork and one another executable).